# How to separate the FooterTemplate in kendo grid to 2 rows in export excel - Angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular6, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a grid in a angular 6 project , 
the footer in the grid contains 2 types of data : custom sum and custom avg 
when i say custom i mean that we have are own logic on how to do the calculation  with the grid data.
[this is how the footer looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiEin.png)

when i export to excel, the footer exported as 1 row and i want to separate it into 2 rows.

the export itself works fine, i just need to separate the footer into 2 rows

footer code:

```
  <ng-template kendoGridFooterTemplate let-dataItem let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex" >
  <div>
    <span *ngIf="columnIndex === 2">{{'average' | translate}}</span>
    <div *ngIf="item.avg">
      <span [ngClass]="getAvg(item.field) > 0 ? 'green' : 'red' ">{{getAvg(item.field) | number: '2.'}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span *ngIf="columnIndex === 2">{{'sum' | translate}}</span>
    <div *ngIf="item.sum">
      <span [ngClass]="getSum(item.field) > 0 ? 'green' : 'red' ">{{getSum(item.field)  | number: '2.'}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

i already tried to check if i can add more then 1 footer and i couldn't find any documentation about it

solution someone :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, 
in onExcelExport(e: any) i can access to the cells in the excel sheet and edit them 
so i just deleted the last row 
and insert manually the data i needed 
so the code looks like this:

the grid settings: 
           `<kendo-grid *ngIf="gridData"
            [data]="gridData"
            [pageSize]="state.take"
            [skip]="state.skip"
            [sort]="state.sort"
            [filter]="state.filter"
            filterable="menu"
            (filterChange)="filterChange($event)"
            [navigable]="true"
            (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
            [sortable]="{
            allowUnsort: true,
            mode:'multiple'} "
            [selectable]="true"
            (excelExport)="onExcelExport($event)">`

the function look like this

```
  onExcelExport(e: any) {
// delete last row in the excel sheet
   const rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;
   rows.pop();

// push new row by initiate new cell array, looping throw state to get the the right field
   const cellsSum = [];
   const rowsLength = rows[rows.length - 1].cells.length;
   for (let i = 0; i < rowsLength; i++) {
     const field =
       this.employeeColumnService.state.employeeDetailsColumns.find(x => x.title ===   rows[0].cells[i].value.toString()).field;

    cellsSum.push({value: this.getSum(field)});
  }
}
   rows.push({type: "data", cells: cellsSum});
```